# I need only date value part and time value part using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two parameters one for date and another for time, and i need date value part and time values part.

My two parameters are below.

```
 // For Date parameter
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01-jan-1999", "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  bo.Dateused5 = dt;

        // For Time parameter
     string Fromtiming = ddl_FromHours.SelectedItem.ToString() + ":" +    ddl_FromMinutes.SelectedItem.ToString();
    DateTime InterviewTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Fromtiming);//StartTime
bo.Dateused4 = InterviewTime;//InterviewTime
```

so i need to send mail to the candidate to only date part, should not    contain time and time part, should not contain date.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01-jan-1999", "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string mailDate = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");// will give 01-jan-1999
string date = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"); // will give 01-01-1999
```

You can also try using [`String.Format()`](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
string mailDate = String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt); // will give 01-01-1999
```

Comment: Did you checked, i used two dropdownlist for time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToShortDateString()`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01-jan-1999", "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var date = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

Note that it uses date format attached to the current thread's culture info.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use strings rather than dates, so change the type of your variables to string so that

```
bo.Dateused5 = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

would set Dateused5 to a string of the date component, then

```
bo.Dateused4 = InterviewTime.ToString("HH:MM");
```

would set Dateused4 to the time component.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test your code but I am very sure there are Functions `"DateValue"` and `"TimeValue"` you can make use of.

Something like,

```
Format(DateValue(any datetime), "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

gives you Only Date in the specified format. Similar way for `TimeValue`